# Проверочное слово для сущ. «тепло»

Tags: орфография, проверочные-слова

Почему для слова *тепло* проверочное слово *тёплый*, если в корнях совершенно разные звуки?

Comment: "Совершенно разные" - это [ф] и [ы]. Например.

Comment: @Niemand. Скажите, пожалуйста, а есть звуки просто разные, а не совершенно разные. Приведите пример, если Вам нетрудно.

Comment: @Sharon, а вот Людмила в своём ответе привела пример разных, но близких фонем. Вы читали? Надо бы и плюсик поставить, это ответ профессионала. Хотя бы за то, что вы "очень давно задумывались над этим вопросом", а тут вам всё на блюдечке принесли.

Comment: @Niemand. При чем тут ответ Людмилы, меня заинтересовало Ваше суждение о звуках. Ведь это не Людмила так сказала, а Вы. Вам нетрудно будет объяснить, что Вы имели в виду. Это я чисто из любопытства, ну не просто же Вы сделали такую запись. А содержание ее от меня как-то ускользает. А ответ Людмилы, конечно, хорош, и был он очень кстати,  но он не для школьников.  А мне как раз детство вспомнилось, вот я и отвечала сама себе, а заодно всей средней  школе. Для учащихся суть важна,  а исторические подробности им пока сложно понять.

Comment: @Niemand Я еще вот почему спрашиваю. Ведь одна из школ определяет фонему как звукоряд, то есть звуки-то акустически разные, а тем не менее связанные между собой, к одной фонеме принадлежат. Вдруг, думаю я, вы их как раз и определите, ну чисто интуитивно. С другой стороны,  есть такое понятие, как разные фонемы. Ну разве Вам не интересно стало?  Вроде бы свой язык,  а такой загадочный.

Comment: @Sharon, мало ли что мне интересно. Чтобы разбираться в этом не то что досконально, а хотя бы сносно, нужно иметь соответствующее образование - и я это вполне осознаю. И "интуицией" тут никак не обойтись. Интуиция - это не что-то данное свыше как некий "подарок", она возникает тогда, когда от работы дым из ушей пошел. Так что ответ Людмилы меня полностью устраивает - на пальцах прояснила довольно сложные вещи.

Comment: @Niemand Спасибо за Ваше мнение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Проверочное слово для сущ. «тепло»

Как вариант: [**те́плиться**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F&all=x%20&all=x).

Answer (score 1):

Изменение е —> о, происходившее в древнерусском и старорусском языках, поддерживалось изначальной функциональной близостью фонем <е> - <о>.
Подобная близость существовала уже в праславянский период. Гласные *е, *о могли чередоваться в пределах одного и того же корня, и их мена указывала на изменение грамматического значения.

Чередованием *е // *о обеспечивалось противопоставление разных способов глагольного действия (однократные — многократные действия и т.п.) или общее противопоставление глагольной основы по отношению к именной. Иными словами, чередование *е // *о является классическим праславянским чередованием в корнях, так называемым качественным чередованием гласных, праиндоевропейским по происхождению. Ср.: нести — носити — НОША,  везоу — возити — возъ.

Далее, гласные *е, *о обеспечивали варьирование окончаний в твердой и мягкой разновидностях склонения, т.е. выполняли одинаковую грамматическую функцию. Ср.: ед.ч. им.н. сел-о пол-е, дв.ч. д.-тв.п. ;ед.ч. зв.п. жено — земле, и т.д. Данная вариативность возникла уже в общеславянский период и была связана с изменением ряда гласного в позиции после мягкого (палатального) согласного: *selom — poljom —> *selo — *poljo —» *selo — *pol.io —> село — поле.

Таким образом, уже в праславянский период гласные фонемы <*е>, <*о> могли быть тождественны по грамматическому значению и варьировались в соответствии с позиционными условиями: *'о —> уе. Функциональная близость данных звуков усилилась после падения редуцированных.

В раннем древнерусском языке сближение [е| — [о| было также связано с тем, что категория лабиализованности гласных не получила, видимо, окончательного развития. То есть <е> — <о> различались прежде всего рядом (передним и непередним), а признак лабиализации был вторичным. Это подтверждается использованием о на месте греческого а в заимствованиях: кровать и др.

В XI в. признак ряда гласных был нейтрализован, и гласные [е] — [о] сделались позиционными вариантами одной фонемы.

https://studme.org/209688/literatura/foneticheskie_protsessy_period_padeniya_redutsirovannyh

Праслав. *tерlъ -это причастие от глагола топить"заставлять быть тёплым", оно дало прилагательное теплыи с переходом е в ё.

Comment: Простите, но я не понимаю, при чем тут история русского языка, если вопрос о современном правиле. (NB: именно _исключительно_ исторический ответ тут, по-моему, неприемлем.)

Comment: Потому что тёплый - абсолютно верное проверочное слово, е и о - близкие фонемы для славянских языков издревле. Чёрный-чернеть - мы проверяем именно чередованием, это объясняется фонетическими законами языка, тепло - тёплый тоже можем проверить чередованием близких фонем.

Answer (score 0):

Я очень давно задумывалась над этим вопросом, помню, еще в школе хотелось у кого-нибудь спросить, хотя так и не решилась. Потом такой же вопрос мне встречался на форумах.

На сегодняшний день **лично для себя** у меня есть такой ответ.

**Мы не проверяем звуки в обычном понимании**, то есть приведением к сильной позиции. Здесь проверка **условная**: мы просто **устанавливаем наличие парного варианта** с чередованием Е/Ё.

И если такой вариант (историческое чередование Е/Ё, ***тепло — тёплый***) имеет место, то это значит, что в ударной позиции пишется **буква Ё,** а безударной позиции пишется **буква  Е**, которая в устной речи произносится как И.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Ну что же еще сказать? Дело в том, что я даю общий ответ, не только для пары слов ***теплеть — тёплый***.

У нас есть **группа корней с чередованием Е/Ё, и для всех действует единое правило**. Прошло уже немало времени с тех пор, как в наш язык вошла буква Ё, и постепенно **появляются слова с ударной позицией звука Е**: ***теплиться*** и даже ***теплоцентраль***. Но правило для корней Е/Ё эти пока ещё периферийные слова не отменяют, оно продолжает действовать **как единый закон, как их общее прошлое.**

И когда ваши дети пойдут в школу, то, может быть, они спросят: **а почему мы делаем такую проверку?** Возможно, в первом классе учитель скажет, что эти буквы дружат между собой. А если они спросят об этом в пятом классе, то что им рассказать? **О функциональной близости фонем?**

Да только **фонемы** (великое и очень важное для русского правописания открытие XIX века) они в школе не проходят, потому что ученые не в состоянии донести **до обычных пользователей простыми словами суть фонемной теории.** (Дело в том, что они заняты другими, более важными делами).

Впрочем, наверное, дети ни о чем не спросят.

Comment: Теплоцентраль как проверочное не убедительно? Тут Е — ударная.

Comment: *>> потому что ученые не в состоянии донести до обычных пользователей простыми словами суть фонемной теории.* Какие плохие ученые... И ученые-физики тоже плохие: они не в состоянии донести до обычных пользователей простыми словами суть квантовой теории и общей теории относительности. Кстати, а кто такие "обычные пользователи"?

Comment: Обычные пользователи - это те, которые не изучали фонологическую теорию на филологических факультетах. Таких людей большинство, в том числе это школьники. К тому же филологию часто не изучают, а просто проходят на первом курсе, чтобы потом забыть о ней совершенно. Предмет излагается очень сложно, изучаются разные фонологические школы, так что и студентам не очень понятно, зачем им всё это нужно. То есть  фонологию превратили в нечто наукообразное и не имеющее практической пользы, в то время как с ее помощью можно ясно и просто объяснить многие вопросы из тех, которые  не объясняются никак.

Comment: Ну вот, вам здесь очень просто объяснили. Без всяких фонологических школ.

Comment: Мне просто объяснили, что для слова тёплый (ну чисто случайно) нашлись более поздние родственные слова с  ударной позицией Е. А как же объяснить проверку для других слов, где нет такого Е?